# Inset lists with text

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to do a nice layout table like that: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-forms-inset.html

Text label on the left and then input/information aligned on the right.

When I insert inputs, selects, etc. it is aligned correctly on the right. However I am not sure how to insert simple text so it is aligned correctly on the right. Is there a <> tag I need to surround my text with so it is correctly aligned?

Thank you for your help.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
    </li>
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
        THE TEXT I WOULD LIKE TO SEE RIGHT-ALIGNED.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example: https://tinker.io/71d3c/1

Comment: Can you put together a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), showing what CSS you're using, and where we're starting from to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a class **ui-input-text** like this:

```
<label for="textarea" class="ui-input-text">Textarea:</label>
THE TEXT I WOULD LIKE TO SEE RIGHT-ALIGNED.
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YA8f6/

**EDIT:**

And here's an example with right alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/DqD7X/

Comment: I might be missing something, but the text doesn't appear to be right-aligned in that demo.

Comment: If you want to have a table that looks like in your example then text should not be aligned to the right, all other fields have a label with 20% width and rest is aligned to its label. I will add you another example with a right alignment.

Comment: I am so sorry if I didn't explain my self correctly the first time... First, the link I follow, I don't see any code in the HTML/JS boxes, perhaps their is someting I miss. Also, what I would like to see is something similar to a table row, like having one cell with Textarea and the other cell with the text. So the text won't overlap with the first cell "Textarea". If you want me to edit my question and perhaps add a screenshot I will do. Thank you again for your help. As you see in your first example, the text goes below "Textarea" if it is too long. However, thx for the first reply again.

Comment: Well it seems like class="ui-input-text" solved my problem. Sorry, jsfiddle that wasn't working was confusing me on the final solution.